# Leaflet/PHP finding polyline points either side of mouse click

Tags: php, leaflet

I am using Leaflet to draw a polyline made up of latlon points A, B, C, D, E.  If I click a random place along that line, I get the click's latlon and from that use some PHP to find the closest latlon point in the polyline.  Let's say it knows point B is the closest.

What I don't know is whether (assuming direction of travel is from A to E) I have clicked in front of or behind point B, in other words am I between A and B or between B and C?

This is where I am stuck.  Not asking for code, but is it possible to use PHP to see if a latlon falls on a line between two other latlon points?  Maybe looking at whether the angle is collinear?  Or is there an easier method I am missing?  Many thanks for any pointers to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - actually this is bad over short distances because the thickness of the polyline can throw out the bearing by quite a few degrees, especially when the click is close to a point.  Back to the drawing board.

---

I decided to try getting the bearing from the click point to the closest point, then seeing whether that bearing matches A-B or B-C.

```
function bearing($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2){
$radians = atan2(asin($lon1-$lon2)*cos($lat2),
cos($lat1)*sin($lat2) - sin($lat1)*cos($lat2)*cos($lon1-$lon2)); 
$degrees = abs(rad2deg($radians));
return $degrees;
}
echo bearing(51.6909727036, -2.0277718088, 51.6898945656, -2.0241979535);
echo bearing(51.690195, -2.025175, 51.6898945656, -2.0241979535);
```

This returns the following:

154.17654569436 (point B to point C)

154.61713565813 (click point to point B)

Not sure why the bearing is not exactly the same as I have limited the mouse click to only work if the polyline is clicked.  But I think this will be close enough for my purposes.  Would still be very interested in any better way to tackle this.  Thanks.